# I need to extract data from a dynamic table on a website, I want to use Jsoup (Java)

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup, extract

I'm using Jsoup to extract data from a table on a website. The content of this table is dynamic, there is a refresh button that updates the rows when I click on it.

I tried to extrapolate the data with Jsoup, but it's like I cannot see the rows of the table when I analyze the HTML page. (parse method). When I click on the refresh button, a JavaScript function is called.

Do you have any suggestions? I read that Jsoup is not able to extract dynamic values from an HTML page? true? Do I have to use some other library? Here is the HTML code of the page extracted from the Chrome DevTools (Element section of the tool)

This is what I see when I go to the Chrome DevTools in the "Element" section:

[image: the data to be extracted]

I want extract the "yellow data".

This is what I see when I go to the chrome developer tool in the "Source" section:

```
<div id="datatable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer" style="display:none;margin-bottom: 50px;min-height:585px">
  <div class="row" style="margin:0px:padding:0px">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" style="width: 1100px;margin:0px !important;padding:0px !important;" role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable_info">
        <thead>
          <tr role="row">
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Event Date/Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 100px;">TITLE_COLUMN1</th>
            <th class="hCenter sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 40px;"></th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Event Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 250px;">TITLE_COLUMN2</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Bet: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 100px;">TITLE_COLUMN3</th>
            <th class="hCenter sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Rating: activate to sort column" style="width: 80px;">TITLE_COLUMN4(%)</th>
            <th class="hCenter sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="SNR Rating: activate to sort column" style="width: 95px;">TITLE_COLUMN5(%)</th>
            <th class="hCenter sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Bookie: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 100px;">TITLE_COLUMN6</th>
            <th class="hCenter sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Back Odds: activate to sort column ascending" style="width:40px;">TITLE_COLUMN7</th>
            <th class="hCenter" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Exchange: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 100px;">TITLE_COLUMN8</th>
            <th class="hCenter sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Lay Odds: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 40px;">TITLE_COLUMN9</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Availibity: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 50px;">TITLE_COLUMN10</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Availibity: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 50px;">
              <img src="/clock.png" width="15px" style="margin-left:10px;" />
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the javascript function that popolate the table:

```
function getData(ratingFrom,ratingTo,oddsFrom,oddsTo,availability,sortColumn=5,sortDirection="desc",offset=0,bookies="",filterbookies="c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c",eventname="",dateFrom="",dateTo="",exchange="",exchanges="",sport="all"){

$("#datatable_processing").css("display","block");
$("#datatable_nodata").css("display","none");
var importo_puntata = parseFloat($("#settings-form input[name=importo-puntata]").val());
var importo_bonus_rimborso = parseFloat($("#settings-form input[name=importo-bonus-rimborso]").val());

$.post("/get_data.php", {"refund":importo_bonus_rimborso,"back_stake":importo_puntata,"name":eventname,"filterbookies":filterbookies,"bookies":bookies,"rating-from":ratingFrom,"rating-to":ratingTo,"odds-from":oddsFrom,"odds-to":oddsTo,"min-liquidity":availability,"sort-column":sortColumn,"sort-direction":sortDirection,"offset":offset,"date-from":dateFrom,"date-to":dateTo,"exchange":exchange,"exchanges":exchanges,'sport':sport}, function(data){
    var allData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    var paginationHtml = "<li class=\"paginate_button previous disabled\" aria-controls=\"datatable\" tabindex=\"0\" id=\"datatable_previous\"><a href=\"#\">Precedente</a></li>";
    paginationHtml+= "<li class=\"paginate_button next\" aria-controls=\"datatable\" tabindex=\"0\" id=\"datatable_next\"><a href=\"#\">Seguente</a></li>";
    $("ul.pagination").html(paginationHtml);

    if(allData.data.length>0)
    {    
        if(allData.bookmakers.length>0)
        {
            if(allData.bookmakers.length>1)
            {
                var html =  '<option value="all">Tutti i Bookmakers</option>';
                $.each(allData.bookmakers, function(i, item) {
                    if(filterbookies == item.id.toString())
                        html  += '<option value="'+item.id.toString()+'" selected="selected">'+capitalizeFirstLetter(item.name)+'</option>';
                    else    
                        html  += '<option value="'+item.id.toString()+'">'+capitalizeFirstLetter(item.name)+'</option>';
                });

                $("#bookmaker").css("display","inline-block");
                $("#bookmaker").html(html);
            }
            else if(allData.bookmakers.length==1)
            {
                var html = '<option value="'+allData.bookmakers[0].id.toString()+'" selected="selected">'+capitalizeFirstLetter(allData.bookmakers[0].name)+'</option>';
                $("#bookmaker").html(html);
            }
        }

        if(allData.exchanges.length>1 && allData.bookmakers.length >1)
        {
                var html =  '<option value="all">Tutti gli Exchanges</option>';
                $.each(allData.exchanges, function(i, item) {
                        html  += '<option value="'+item.toString()+'">'+capitalizeFirstLetter(item.toString())+'</option>';
                });

                $("#exchange").css("display","inline-block");
                $("#exchange").html(html);
        }
        else if ($("input[name=exchanges]").val() == "all")
        {
                $("#exchange").css("display","inline-block");
        }


        $("#datatable tbody").html("");
        var html = "";



        $.each(allData.data, function(i, item) {
            var json = allData.data[i];
            var redRating = "";
            if(json.rating>=100)
                redRating= " redrating ";

            html  +=  "<tr role=\"row\" style=\"background-color: #fff !important;\" back-odds=\""+json.back_odds+"\" lay-odds=\""+json.lay_odds+"\" competition=\""+json.competition+"\" country=\""+json.country_code+"\" exchange=\""+json.exchange+"\" >"+
                       "<td>"+json.opendate+"</td>"+
                       "<td class=\"hCenter\"><img src=\"/images/"+json.sport+".png\" /></td>"+
                       "<td>"+json.event_name+"</td>"+
                       "<td>"+json.bet+"</td>"+
                       "<td class=\"hCenter sorting_1\"><span class=\"rating"+redRating+"\">"+json.rating+"</span></td>"+
                       "<td class=\"hCenter sorting_1\"><span class=\"snrrating\">"+json.snr_rating.toString()+".00"+"</span>"+
                       "<img src=\"/images/calculator.png\" class=\"calculator\""+
                       "  attrib-sport=\""+json.sport+"\" attrib-exchange=\""+json.exchange+"\" attrib-competition=\""+json.competition+"\" attrib-country=\""+json.country_code+"\" attrib-eventdate=\""+json.opendate+"\" attrib-eventname=\""+json.event_name+"\" attrib-bet=\""+json.bet+"\" attrib-market=\""+json.market_type+"\" attrib-rating=\""+json.rating+"\" attrib-odds-provider_id=\""+json.odds_provider_fk+"\"  attrib-odds-provider=\""+capitalizeFirstLetter(json.odds_provider)+"\" attrib-back-odds=\""+json.back_odds+"\" attrib-lay-odds=\""+json.lay_odds+"\" attrib-availability=\""+json.availability+"\" attrib-bookie-bet-url=\""+json.bookie_bet_url+"\" attrib-betfair-bet-url=\""+json.betfair_bet_url+"\" "+
                       " /></td>"+
                       "<td class=\" hCenter\"><img src=\"/images/"+json.odds_provider_fk+".png\" width=\"80\" /></td>"+
                       "<td class=\" hCenter back\" ><span>"+json.back_odds+"</span></td>"+
                       "<td class=\" hCenter\" ><img src=\"/images/"+json.exchange+".png\" width=\"80\" /></td>"+
                       "<td class=\" hCenter lay\" ><span>"+json.lay_odds+"</span></td>"+
                       "<td>&nbsp; &#8364;"+json.availability+"</td>"+
                       "<td>"+json.update_time.toString()+"</td>"+
                    "</tr>";
        });



        var allEvents = parseInt(allData.allEventsCount);
        if(allEvents>10)
        {    
            allEvents = allEvents - 10;
            var j=0;
            var pageStart = parseInt(allData.offset);
            if(pageStart<9)
                pageStart=1;
                else
                pageStart-=4;

            var pageHtml = "";
            for(var i=pageStart;i<=parseInt(allEvents/10);i++)
            {
                var current = "";
                if((i-1==parseInt(allData.offset) && pageStart!=1) || (pageStart==1 && i-1==allData.offset))
                    current = "paginate_current disabled";

                pageHtml += "<li class=\"paginate_button paginate "+current+"\" aria-controls=\"datatable\" tabindex=\"0\"><a href=\"\" class=\"paginate\">"+i.toString()+"</a></li>";

                j++;
                if(j>9)
                    break;
            }

            $("#datatable_previous").after(pageHtml);
        }

        $("#datatable_previous").click(function(event){
            if($(this).hasClass("disabled"))
                {event.preventDefault();return;}
            var sortColumn = $("#search-form input[name=sort-column]").val();
            var sortDirection = $("#search-form input[name=sort-direction]").val();

            var ratingFrom = $("#search-form input[name=rating-from]").val();
            var ratingTo=$("#search-form input[name=rating-to]").val();
            var oddsFrom=$("#search-form input[name=odds-from]").val();
            var oddsTo=$("#search-form input[name=odds-to]").val();
            var availability=$("#search-form input[name=availability]").val();
            var offset=parseInt($("#search-form input[name=offset]").val())-1;
            var bookies = $("#search-form input[name=bookies]").val();
            var filterbookies = $("#bookmaker").val();
             var dateFrom = $("#date-from").val();
                    var dateTo = $("#date-to").val();
            var teamname = $("#event-name").val();
             var exchange = $("#exchange").val();
             var exchanges = $("#search-form input[name=exchanges]").val();
            var sport = $("#sport").val();
                 getData(ratingFrom,ratingTo,oddsFrom,oddsTo,availability,sortColumn,sortDirection,offset,bookies,filterbookies,teamname,dateFrom,dateTo,exchange,exchanges,sport);

        });

        $("#datatable_next").click(function(event){
            if($(this).hasClass("disabled"))
                {event.preventDefault();return;}

            var sortColumn = $("#search-form input[name=sort-column]").val();
            var sortDirection = $("#search-form input[name=sort-direction]").val();

            var ratingFrom = $("#search-form input[name=rating-from]").val();
            var ratingTo=$("#search-form input[name=rating-to]").val();
            var oddsFrom=$("#search-form input[name=odds-from]").val();
            var oddsTo=$("#search-form input[name=odds-to]").val();
            var availability=$("#search-form input[name=availability]").val();
            var offset=parseInt($("#search-form input[name=offset]").val())+1;
            var bookies = $("#search-form input[name=bookies]").val();
            var filterbookies = $("#bookmaker").val();
            var dateFrom = $("#date-from").val();
                    var dateTo = $("#date-to").val();
            var teamname = $("#event-name").val();
             var exchange = $("#exchange").val();
             var exchanges = $("#search-form input[name=exchanges]").val();
            var sport = $("#sport").val();
                 getData(ratingFrom,ratingTo,oddsFrom,oddsTo,availability,sortColumn,sortDirection,offset,bookies,filterbookies,teamname,dateFrom,dateTo,exchange,exchanges,sport);

        });

        $("ul.pagination>li.paginate>a.paginate").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var offset = parseInt($(this).html())-1;
            var sortColumn = $("#search-form input[name=sort-column]").val();
            var sortDirection = $("#search-form input[name=sort-direction]").val();

            var ratingFrom = $("#search-form input[name=rating-from]").val();
            var ratingTo=$("#search-form input[name=rating-to]").val();
            var oddsFrom=$("#search-form input[name=odds-from]").val();
            var oddsTo=$("#search-form input[name=odds-to]").val();
            var availability=$("#search-form input[name=availability]").val();
            var bookies = $("#search-form input[name=bookies]").val();
            var filterbookies = $("#bookmaker").val();
            var teamname = $("#event-name").val();
             var dateFrom = $("#date-from").val();
                    var dateTo = $("#date-to").val();
             var exchange = $("#exchange").val();
             var exchanges = $("#search-form input[name=exchanges]").val();
            var sport = $("#sport").val();
                 getData(ratingFrom,ratingTo,oddsFrom,oddsTo,availability,sortColumn,sortDirection,offset,bookies,filterbookies,teamname,dateFrom,dateTo,exchange,exchanges,sport);
        });

        $("#datatable_wrapper .pageNumber").html((parseInt(allData.offset)*10)+1);
        $("#datatable_wrapper .pageCount").html(allData.data.length+(parseInt(allData.offset)*10));
        $("#datatable_wrapper .allEventsCount").html(allData.allEventsCount);

        if((allData.data.length+(parseInt(allData.offset)*10)) < allData.allEventsCount)
            $("#datatable_next").removeClass("disabled");
        else
        {
            $("#datatable_next").removeClass("disabled");
            $("#datatable_next").addClass("disabled");
        }

        if(parseInt(allData.offset)>=1)
            $("#datatable_previous").removeClass("disabled");
        else
        {
            $("#datatable_previous").removeClass("disabled");
            $("#datatable_previous").addClass("disabled");
        }

        $("#datatable tbody").html(html);
        $("#datatable_wrapper").css("display","block");
        $("#datatable th").removeClass("sorting_desc");
        $("#datatable th").removeClass("sorting_asc");
        $("#datatable th").removeClass("sorting");
        $("#datatable th").addClass("sorting");
        $("#datatable th").removeAttr("aria-sort");

        $("#search-form input[name=offset]").val(allData.offset);
        $("#search-form input[name=sort-column]").val(allData.sortColumn);
        $("#search-form input[name=sort-direction]").val(allData.sortDirection);

        $($("#datatable th")[allData.sortColumn]).attr('aria-sort',allData.sortDirectionFull);
        $($("#datatable th")[allData.sortColumn]).removeClass("sorting");
        $($("#datatable th")[allData.sortColumn]).addClass("sorting_"+allData.sortDirection);    
        $("#datatable img.calculator").click(function(){

                $("#event-details #calc-event-datetime").val($(this).attr('attrib-eventdate'));
                $("#event-details #calc-event-name").val($(this).attr('attrib-eventname'));

                $("#event-details .event-rating").html($(this).attr('attrib-rating'));
                $("#event-details .event-competition").html($(this).attr('attrib-competition'));
                $("#event-details .event-country").html($(this).attr('attrib-country'));

                $("#right-container input[name=back-odds]").val($(this).attr('attrib-back-odds'));    
                $("#right-container a.bookie-bet-url").attr("href",$(this).attr('attrib-bookie-bet-url'));    

                $("#right-container a.betfair-bet-url").attr("href",$(this).attr('attrib-betfair-bet-url'));    
                if ($(this).attr('attrib-sport') == "tennis" && $(this).attr('attrib-exchange') == "betfair")
                    $("#right-container a.betfair-bet-url").attr("href",$(this).attr('attrib-betfair-bet-url').replace("football","tennis"));    
                $("#right-container input[name=back-commission]").val("0.00");
                $("#right-container input[name=lay-odds]").val($(this).attr('attrib-lay-odds'));    
                $("#right-container input[name=lay-commission]").val("0.05");
                $("#odds-container .event-outcome").html($(this).attr('attrib-bet')+" To Win");
                $("#odds-container span.backTitle").html($(this).attr('attrib-back-odds'));
                $("#odds-container span.layTitle").html($(this).attr('attrib-lay-odds'));
                $("#match-container img.exchangeLogo").attr("src","/images/"+$(this).attr('attrib-exchange')+".png");
                $("#match-container img.sport-img").attr("src","/images/"+$(this).attr('attrib-sport')+".png");
                $("span.event-exchange").html(capitalizeFirstLetter($(this).attr('attrib-exchange')));
                $("span.event-back-oddsprovider").html($(this).attr('attrib-odds-provider'));            
                $("#odds-container span.back-odds").html($(this).attr('attrib-back-odds'));
                $("#odds-container span.lay-odds").html($(this).attr('attrib-lay-odds'));

                $("#odds-container span.backTitle").html($(this).attr('attrib-back-odds'));
                $("#odds-container span.backTitle").html($(this).attr('attrib-back-odds'));

                $("#odds-container img.bookmakerLogo").attr("src","/images/"+$(this).attr('attrib-odds-provider_id').toString()+".png");

                $("#odds-container .event-back-outcome").html($(this).attr('attrib-bet'));
                $("#odds-container .event-lay-outcome").html($(this).attr('attrib-bet'));
                $("#odds-container span.lay-availability").html("&#8364;"+$(this).attr('attrib-availability').toString()+" liquidità");

                var importo_puntata = $("#settings-form input[name=importo-puntata]").val();
                var importo_bonus_rimborso = $("#settings-form input[name=importo-bonus-rimborso]").val();
                $("#right-container input[name=back-stake]").val(importo_puntata);
                $("#right-container input[name=back-refund-stake]").val(importo_bonus_rimborso);

                $("#match-container").dialog({
                    width: 850,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: "Calcolatore - "+$(this).attr('attrib-eventname'),
                    open: function(event, ui) {

                        $("#rbtnSNR").attr("checked",false);
                        $("#rbtnSR").attr("checked",false);
                        $("#rbtnNormal").attr("checked",true);
                        updateCalculator(0);
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 100 }, "fast");
                    }
                }).parent().position({
                    my: 'top+50px',
                    at: 'top',
                    collision: "flip flip",
                    of: $("#datatable_wrapper")
                });
            });
    }
    else
    {
        if(allData.bookmakers.length==1)
        {
            $("#bookmaker").css("display","none");
        }

        $("#datatable_nodata").css("display","block");
        $("#datatable_nodata h3").html("<center>Nessun dato trovato</center>");
        $("#datatable_wrapper").css("display","none");
    }

    $("#datatable_processing").css("display","none");
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I read that Jsoup is not able to extract dynamic values from an html page? true?

True.
Data you're looking for is not in the page source. It's dynamically read as a result of POST to "/get_data.php". Try to get that response as it will contain JSON object. I'd recommend to use some JSON parsing library.

Jsoup is not necessary here but it can be used to easily fetch JSON data:

```
String jsonResponse = Jsoup
    .connect(url + "/get_data.php")
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .timeout(20000)
    .ignoreContentType(true)
    .maxBodySize(0)
    .requestBody("\"refund\":importo_bonus_rimborso,\"back_stake\":importo_puntata,\"name\":eventname,\"filterbookies\":filterbookies,\"bookies\":bookies,\"rating-from\":ratingFrom,\"rating-to\":ratingTo,\"odds-from\":oddsFrom,\"odds-to\":oddsTo,\"min-liquidity\":availability,\"sort-column\":sortColumn,\"sort-direction\":sortDirection,\"offset\":offset,\"date-from\":dateFrom,\"date-to\":dateTo,\"exchange\":exchange,\"exchanges\":exchanges,'sport':sport}")
    .execute().body();
```

Comment: "no don't work" is not enough info to help you. What's the URL of this page?